# $u$ and $v$ are real and imaginary part of a complex function $f(z)$ find $\oint udy+vdx$ over $C$

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Given that $u $ and $v$ be the real and imaginary part of complex function

> $$\frac{1}{z^2-6z+8}$$ of complex variable $z=x+iy$

Let $C$ be the simple closed curve $|z|=3$ in counter clockwise then find the value of the

> $$\oint_C u  \mathrm{d}y+v\mathrm{d}x$$

**solution i tried** -Here the given equation $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^2-6z+8}$ can be written as 
$$\frac{x^2-y^2+8}{(x^2-y^2+8)^2+(2xy-6x-6y)^2}+i\frac{2xy-6x-6y}{(x^2-y^2+8)^2+(2xy-6x-6y)^2}$$

where $$u=\frac{x^2-y^2+8}{(x^2-y^2+8)^2+(2xy-6x-6y)^2}\;\; and \;\;v=\frac{2xy-6x-6y}{(x^2-y^2+8)^2+(2xy-6x-6y)^2}$$

also we have to find the value of >$$\oint_C u  \mathrm{d}y+v\mathrm{d}x$$ also from green's theorem >$$\oint_C u  \mathrm{d}y+v\mathrm{d}x=\int\int_C(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})dxdy$$

when i try of futher solve this the calculations become more and more complicated ,is there any short way or i am missing some hint here .

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can we write
$$
\oint f(z)\;dz = \oint (u+iv)(dx+idy) =
\oint \left(u\;dx - v\;dy \right) + i \left(u\;dy+v\;dx\right)
$$
so that we are computing the imaginary part of $\oint f(z)\;dz$.  And that is easy using the residues of $f$.

Comment: Great answer @GEdgar ,thankyou

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you don't know the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) which is the convenient way of dealing with this kind of problem.

Hint for a direct calculation. We have that $z^2-6z+8=(z-2)(z-4)$ and therefore
$$\frac{1}{z^2-6z+8}=\frac{1/2}{z-2}-\frac{1/2}{z-4}.$$
Now split the integral and note that if $z=x+iy$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then
$$\frac{1}{z-a}=\frac{\overline{z}-a}{|z-a|^2}=\frac{(x-a)-iy}{(x-a)^2+y^2}.$$